# spray-can how to unwrap unmarshalled FormData

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I have something like this:

```
case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/userAction"), headers, entity: HttpEntity.NonEmpty, protocol) =>
  val x = entity.as[spray.http.FormData].merge.asInstanceOf[spray.http.FormData].fields
  sender ! HttpResponse(entity="Got it: " + x)
```

It seems a little bit inconvinient to unwrap the `HttpEntity`, is there a much more elegant way?

Furthermore: is it possible to get the data from inputs with multiple delacred variables? Is there a better way to access FormData, e.g. as Json or HashMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there an actual reason why you are implementing this with spray-can? In routing it's more easier and natural:

```
lazy val yourRoute: Route = {
  (post & path("userAction")) {
    entity(as[SomeType]) { data =>
      // do what you want
    }
  }
}
```

In this version it all comes to the proper unmarshaller for your type (`SomeType`). But if you want to stick with spray-can, you can use spray-httpx unmarshaller. I don't have IDE near to me, but this can like this (actual code from my project with some Scalaz tricks):

```
case request @ HttpRequest(...) =>
  fromTryCatch(request.entity |> unmarshal[SomeType]) // returns Throwable \/ SomeType, like scala's Either type
```

Here it also comes to the right unmarshaller, e.g if you want to get your entity in Json format (i.e spray JsObject), then you need to emit a request with json payload, write `entity(as[JsObject])` and provide an implicit unmarshaller from `spray.json.SprayJsonSupport`. I think that using this approach for `FormData` is a bit overhead, cause for simple Post payload you have `formFields` directive, and you can write:

```
lazy val yourRoute: Route = {
  (post & path("userAction")) {
    formFields(...) { fields => // just enumerate field names from your FormData
      // do what you want
    }
  }
}
```

For Map approach if the same, just add `spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol` into the scope, to add unmarshaller for maps.

Still using spray-routing DSL is far better then dealing with low-level can code. If you still want to use, then take a look at `spray.httpx.unmarshalling` package, it contains different types of unmarshallers, for entity, request and response.